# Inequality for Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a function in the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and let the Fourier transform of $f$ be defined by
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{-ikx} dx
\end{equation}
with inverse
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} \hat{f}(k) e^{ikx} dk
\end{equation}
Then obviously
\begin{equation}
|f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(k)| dk.
\end{equation}
Now I should be able to find the inequality
\begin{equation}
|f(x)|^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(k)|^2(1+k^2) dk.
\end{equation}
I already tried partial integration, observed that $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{1+k^2}dk=\pi$ which may explain why the $\pi$ disappears, tried to find a way of applying Cauchy-Schwartz, but I always get stuck. Does anyone have an idea how to get this inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz does the job:
$$\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(k)|\,dk&=\int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(k)|\,(1+k^2)^{1/2}\,(1+k^2)^{-1/2}\,dk\\
&\le\Bigl(\int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(k)|^2\,(1+k^2)\,dk\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\int_\mathbb{R} (1+k^2)^{-1}\,dk\Bigr)^{1/2}\\
&=\sqrt{\pi}\Bigl(\int_\mathbb{R} |\hat{f}(k)|^2\,(1+k^2)\,dk\Bigr)^{1/2}.
\end{align}$$